# 'Such [something/someone]' OR 'Such a [something/someone]' -Any diference?

Tags: adverbs, adjectives, word-usage

Is there any difference between 'such a something/one' and 'such something/one'?

> He is such fool

**over**

> He is such a fool

Is the former one possible in *any context* or style?

If the article is *must*; does including 'no' makes the former sentence valid?

> He is no such fool

Why?

Comment: You said "'such a/an x' (x-something/somebody) instead of 'such x'", but your examples seem not to support that well. (They seem to suggest the opposite.) In any case, your examples are "no such way" and "such a way", which are similar to "There is a man ..." and "There is no man ...", but with "such" added to the sentences.

Comment: @DamkerngT. changed.

Comment: I have a rather strong feeling that "He is such fool." is ungrammatical.

Comment: @DamkerngT. what do you think about this sentence? ***Who is such fool as to think this wisdom?*** Also, *No Christian is such fool to send a blasphemous message to any Muslim cleric especially when they know the consequences* - CNN Report

Comment: Probably not modern English.

Comment: As for that piece of CNN Report, it's something I wouldn't want to comment on.

Comment: Consider: *"He is a fool!"* --> *"He is such a fool!"*

Comment: @MaulikV That CNN "report" (http://ireport.cnn.com/docs/DOC-1167267) is in their crowd-sourced reporting queue.  It is not written by a native speaker, and was clearly not edited by one either.  It is riddled with grammatical errors and uncommon usages.

Answer (score 3):

The word **such** is used as a predeterminer. (Not concentrating on other uses of **such**, because they are not relevant here)

When it is used as predeterminer, we use *a/an* after **such**. We can also use **such** as a single determiner, without the need of any other determiner, such as *a/an* following it.

**For example -**

> They are **such** idiots. [Here **such** is the only one determiner]
>
> He is **such a** fool. [Here **such** is sued as a predeterminer, and *a/an* follows]
>
> It was **such a** pity that you couldn't be with us.
>
> We have had **such** awful weather lately.

So the bottom line is, we can use both - **such a/an** and **such**, like I have shown in example sentences.

Now coming to your negative sentence confusion with **such**.

The word **no** is used as a determiner - central determiner, that is. (The other use of **no** is not discussed here, as they are not relevant here)

**Determiners** are words which come at the beginning of the **noun phrase**.

There are three types of determiner: central determiner, predeterminer and post determiner. The order in which they occur in a sentence - predeterminer + central determiner + post determiner.

This is the reason we don't say **five the all boys**. We say **all the five boys**. [*all* - predeterminer, *the* - central determiner, *five* - post determiner]

No other pattern of occurrence of these three type of determiners are allowed.

When the central determiner precedes **such**, it's a pro-form modifier. Hence, **no such idiot** is correct.

But **no such a idiot** is incorrect.

Consider this -

> I have seen green balls were there. Where are they? No, you are wrong. There is no *such* balls.

Here the word *such* is a pro-form modifier, replacing *green* - an adjective.

We can say *green ball*, but not *green a ball*, because an adjective can only modify a head noun in a noun phrase structure, it however can't modify a noun phrase.

This is the reason it's incorrect to say - **no such a boy**

Answer (score 2):

> *He is such fool.

The statement needs a determiner:

**He is such *a* fool.**

**He is *no* such fool.**

*He is great singer.

**He is *a* great singer.**

**He is *no* great singer.**

Answer (score 1):

He is such fool.

He is such a fool.

He is no such fool.

Grammatically speaking, you must use an indefinite article (a/an) after "such" when used for emphasizing your description of a singular countable noun phrase. So the second sentence sounds natural, whereas the first one sounds odd.

However, when you use the determiners "some" and "no" before "such", you don't need to use "a/an" after "such" as the following:

He needs to see a psychiatrist or some such person.

He is no such fool. However, it's right to say "He is not such a fool"

There is no such thing as magic. It's also correct to say "there is not such a thing.

Further, as we know the "no" also means "not a/an/one/any", it comes across that when we use "no" before "such", we can't use an indefinite article after "such".  Same is the case with the "some", which is used to refer to something or somebody indefinite or not known. Even some grammarians consider it to be an indefinite article.

Comment: I guess putting *article* emphasizes and not putting it is just a statement. *Yeah, he can do that...he is such shameless guy -I'm not emphasizing 'him' but then *he is such a shameless guy* typically focuses on 'him' what say?

Comment: @Maulik, I am sorry I have no idea. If I say anything, it'll be a bit of a leap in the dark.