# 'Such volume' or 'such a volume'?

Tags: countability

I have looked at [such-something-someone-or-such-a-something-someone-any-diference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44294/such-something-someone-or-such-a-something-someone-any-diference), and it didn't help. There the stress seems to be on the word 'such', followed by the count noun 'fool'. Here my focus is on the word 'volume', which I think can be both countable and noncountable.

Question 1

> A tremendous amount of information was given to us. The sorting through of such volume of information is time consuming.

Is this okay, or must we have "a" before "volume"? If "a" is also okay, what is the difference in the two sentences?

Question 2
<strike>Second, the ODO says "[volume](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/volume)" is both countable and noncountable? Does this fact affect the answeer to my first question?</strike>

EDIT:
Are both the following acceptable? If so, what is the difference?

(I am trying to keep the context open to allow for any possible situation in which each sentence could be grammatical.)

> Such a volume of noise is unacceptable!

and

> Such volume of noise is unacceptable!

Comment: I think that, in this case, the **a** is recommended... imagine saying "Such a [large] volume".

Comment: To your new question, yes. Both of those are acceptable, with the latter being more likely in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

*Volume* is noncount in contexts where it contrasts either with alternative measures (60% alcohol *by volume*, as opposed to *by weight*) or with alternative scales (purchase *in volume*, as opposed to *individually* or *in small lots*). Neither of those contexts obtains here: you speak of comparing one volume with another, or with all others, so it is treated as a distinct item and requires a determiner.

Comment: I'd also discard OP's ***the*** and ***of***. *Sorting through such a volume of information* sounds much better to me. But personally I don't really like *volume* here in the first place, since *information* doesn't normally occupy much if any physical space. I'd prefer *such a **quantity** of information*.

Comment: I am going to edit my question to better get at Question Number 2.

Answer (score 2):

You need *a* in front of *volume*.

*Volume* can mean *a collection of X*, so it's countable (you aren't counting the X, you are counting the *collection* or *set* of it), unlike something like *sugar*, *knowledge*, etc.  You can pluralize it and it will make sense:

> Alice gave me a huge pile of paperwork, and then Bob gave me an even bigger pile of paperwork.  Together, these contain two vast volumes of data, so when it's in the computer, it will take the computer a while to process.

That's a contrived example but I hope you get the idea.