# 'Such a' or 'such '?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-choice

> ... so that the cost of such **a** broadcast stays zero.

Is this sentence correct ? or should I omit the `a`?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide more context?

Comment: Broadcast as a noun can be countable and uncountable. So we should know its exact meaning to decide.

Comment: I've racked my brains, but I can't think of *any* context where it would be syntactically valid to dispense with the article in OP's "text fragment" as cited.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hi! This is me again, Sina. I had these in mind when I posted the comment: 1 a radio or TV program (c), 2. The act of broadcasting something (u). Please tell me what's my mistake. I promise not to ask for paraphrasing;-)

Comment: @Avicenna: I don't think countable or uncountable is an issue here. Note that both your definitions include articles *(**a** radio or TV program, **the** act of broadcasting)*. The only really valid way of avoiding the article would be something like *The cost of **such broadcasting** is negligible*.

Comment: I can see the article being omitted in a sort of legalese phrasing, for example something like, "If a fee is charged for a broadcast, then the receiver shall reimburse the sender so that the cost of such broadcast stays zero."

Comment: @FumbleFingers please take a look at [this](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/broadcast),I mean the count and noncount part. In Cambridge dictionary the noncount form is listed as *broadcasting* but in Webster's Learners dictionary both the count and noncount forms are listed as *broadcast*. I am gradually doubting the authenticity of Webster's!

Comment: @Avicenna: Actually, when I looked at the example in that M-W Learners definition for noncount usage, my first thought was that I would have said *The judge decided to allow **broadcasting** of the trial*. Not that I find ***broadcast*** completely *wrong* - it's just not my preferred choice. So I checked Google Books to find they claim 317 instances of *allow broadcasting of*, compared to 201 of *allow broadcast of*. Things like this aren't always black & white, but I may investigate the underlying *principle* a bit deeper on ELU.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Such" vs. "Such a"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/64937/such-vs-such-a)

Answer (score 3):

It is correct, because "broadcast" is singular.

> such a broadcast

vs.

> such broadcasts