# When to use "such" before a noun and when to use "such a/an"?

Tags: zero-article

Should you put an “a” here in the blank after *such*?

> Alpha is supposed to warrant the connection between Beta and Gamma. But ____ connection seems to be already warranted.

Which one is correct instead of ____, *such* or *such a*?

Comment: @Eilia That’s an answer, true enough, but not, I think, a correct one. See below.

Answer (score 6):

**Tom’s Thumbrule**: If you can say *some* with a singular noun and the expression still be grammatical, then you can use *such* with that singular noun without requiring an indefinite article. But if you cannot do so, then you must add an indefinite article in both cases. That’s because this is related to nominal ***[countability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_noun)***.

## On Countability

In shorter words, all that matters here is whether *connection* is countable, which it is:

- Such **a connection is** subject to verification.
- Such **connections are** subject to verification.

Contrast with the normally uncountable *bravery*:

- Such **bravery is** to be commended.

Because we do not normally say **a bravery*, nor **some braveries* either.

#### Thumbrule Application

If you try the “*some* for *such*” substitution I suggested, this becomes clear:

- **Some bravery** is to be commended.  ← *grammatical*
- ***Some connection** is subject to verification.  ← ***ɴᴏᴛ*** grammatical❗

#### There’s More Than One Way to Do It

There are cases that legitimately admit both scenarios:

- Such **honor is** to be revered.
- Such **an honor is** to be bestowed.
- Such **honors are** to be bestowed.

The first posits *honor* as a quality, the other two as enumerable items (such as a prize perhaps).

For learners of English whose first languages are bereft of articles,
getting used to when the zero-article applies versus when one or another definite or indefinite one does so is something that often proves annoying or difficult, or both. You just have to get used to it.

Comment: Can't we use "connection" with "some"? Please check "some connection between/among/with" in google search.

Comment: @user204489 Yes, but not by itself. You cannot say "Some connection is subject to verification".  There it’s a count noun, so would need to be in the plural.